# Entity Framework same entity in multiple navigation collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an issue updating specific entity graph, containing entity with two navigation properties of the same type (two foreign keys to the same table)

[image: Here is DB structure]

So, the product can participate in promo (one to many) and also promo has a set on products, using as a gifts (many to many). You buying one product and get another one (or many) for free if there is a promo associated with the product.

Here is my class structure:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? PromoItemId { get; set; }

    public virtual PromoItem PromoItem { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PromoItem> AddedToPromoItems { get; set; }
}

public class PromoItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("PromoItem")]
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> AddedProducts { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to update PromoItem entity including Products and AddedProducts collections using single EF context:

```
    public void Update(PromoItem entity)
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            // original entity
            var originalEntity = context.PromoItems
                .Include(p => p.Products)
                .Include(p => p.AddedProducts)
                .Single(p => p.Id == entity.Id);

            // update products (one to many)
            var productIds = entity.Products.Select(ap => ap.Id).ToList(); // get products ids
            var products = context.Products // load products from DB
                .Where(p => productIds.Contains(p.Id))
                .ToList();
            originalEntity.Products.UpdateFrom(products, context); // here is Add, Remove etc to collection


            // update added products (many to many)
            // *********************
            // one of the product here was removed from Products collection, so it already attached to the  context and has "Deleted" state!
            // *********************
            var addedProductIds = entity.AddedProducts.Select(ap => ap.Id).ToList(); // get products ids
            var addedProducts = context.Products // load products from DB
                .Where(p => addedProductIds.Contains(p.Id))
                .ToList();
            originalEntity.AddedProducts = addedProducts; // assign many to many collection

            // update entity
            context.Update(originalEntity, entity);

            // save changes
            context.SaveChanges(); // here I got an error "Adding a relationship with an entity which is in the Deleted state is not allowed."
        }
    }
```

Problem appears when same product is in both collections. Let's say I want to remove it from one collection and add to another. I need to update only base entity and it associacions (not products itself).
How to load the same entity twice with different state within same DB context?

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this problem as well, and the not-so-clean solution was to map the join table as an entity and use its navigation properties instead of having two relationships of a different kind between the same 2 entity models.

```
public class PromoItemProduct
{
     public int ProductId { get; set; }
     public int PromoItemId { get; set; }


     public virtual Product Products { get; set; }
     public virtual PromoItem PromoItem { get; set; }
}
```

And then change the many-to-many navigation properties of the Product and PromoItem models to PromoItemProduct.

Comment: Yeah, not so clean.. What if I'd have two many-to-many or two one-to-many associations?